# How to use Refit Settings in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, bearer-token, webapi, refit

I am creating Android and IoS apps.
I use refit for calling the WebAPI.
The WebAPI need bearer authorization.
But i think that is bad to pass the token every request.
I found to do that in the GitHub, but i don't know how to use refit settings in xamarin forms.
I need to Set either `AuthorizationHeaderValueGetter` or `AuthorizationHeaderValueWithParamGetter` in the `RefitSettings` instance.

Can someone help me ? please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var ApiRefit = RestService.For<IApiRefit>("URL", new RefitSettings
              {
                AuthorizationHeaderValueGetter = async () => await GetTokenAsync()
              });


  [Headers("User-Agent: Your App", "Authorization: Bearer")]
  public interface IApiRefit
   {
       .........
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in a Header parameter to your method call.

[image: screenshot of the same]

Comment: where i pass the Header parameter ?